# Separate editor for debugging

Tags: navision

I wonder why in navision there is a separate window for debugging.

And why not that you can debug directly in the code, like in most of the code editors, for example visual studio, netbeans?

Comment: "You just holding it wrong"(c)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, NAV have a separate window for debugging code. This happens in all version of **NAV** from **MBS Navision 3.7** to **NAV 2016**.

It is this way because **NAV** is a **ERP** It's not just a code editor.

For example when you're debugging code NAV window is block because NAV is busy and in this moment other window appear (debugger window) to be able debug the code and NAV window only unlocks when the debugger window finish her work.

The same happens in the other **ERP** of **Microsoft**, **Microsoft Dynamics AX**.

Regards,